# How to hard press button in iPhone and detact 3D touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

> I have on Unbutton and i want to open detail page on hard press on it.

so how it possible let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#pragma mark - Previewing delegate
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    UIViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    detailVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 568.0);
    previewingContext.sourceRect = self.btnDetail.frame;
    return detailVC;
}

- (void)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit{
    [self showViewController:viewControllerToCommit sender:self];
}
```